# Cant Escape Emergency Mode to Default Mode Pop!_OS After "Windows Volume Repair" and fsck

Tags: mount, boot, dual-boot, uefi, acpi

I am dual booting Pop_OS! 22.04. I booted into Windows, finished what I was doing there then went back to boot into Pop!_OS and discovered it would not boot, it was giving me some sort of diagnostic message at this point -- I didn't catch it, but it said something about not booting. I made the mistake of [letting "Windows Volume Repair" take a crack at it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043636/cant-get-past-ubuntu-emergency-mode-w-windows-7-dual-boot-after-running-boot-re) and now it does not even show the message. It just seems to hang after my system splash screen (at first it shows a company logo on the side, then it disappears -- still showing the splash screen, and hangs, I think after the logo disappears it has handed off the process too the OS).

I [tried running `fsck`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256372/emergency-mode-during-fsck) with `-f`, `-c`, `-a`, I also booted into a Live USB (no repair option, I did not make a recovery partition), and tried running `e2fsck` from there -- no dice, I tried editing `/etc/fstab` and commenting/uncommenting some of the possible combos, and changing a few values (keeping backup comments and backing up `/etc/fstab` itself).

Im at a bit of a loss, after running `journalctl -xb` I see a few errors/warnings, I have looked up a few of them but did not find resolutions. Note: I am transcribing these from screen shots

- W: `system76_acpi: Loading out of tree module taints kernel` (highlighted in orange, guessing that means warning, *I* will use W: to denote that)
- W: `No caching page found Assuming drive cache: write through`
- E: `ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0PB2], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210930/dswload2-162)` (highlighted in red, assuming an error, *I* will denote it with E:)
- E: `ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210930/psobject220)`
  This error is repeated with a note in between the two lines `ACPI: Skipping pass of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)
- W: `acpi PNP0C14:03 duplicate WMI GUID (<GUID HERE>) (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)`
- W: `amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: PSP runtime database doesn't exist`
- W: `amdgpu SRAT table not found`
- W: `ATPX version 1. functions 0x00000001 ATPX Hybrid Graphics` (I tried switching to discrete in the bios, no dice)
- W: `device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABBLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements...`
- W: `platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard`
- W: `platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1` (this goes from 1-8)
- N: `Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...`
- W: `pci 0000:00:00.2: Cant derive routing for PCI INT A`
- W: `pci 0000:00:00.2: PCI INT A: not connected`
- E: `Failed to load kernel module 'autofs4'`
- E: `Failed to find module 'lp'`
- E: `Failed to find module 'ppdev'`
- E: `Failed to find module 'parport_pc`
- E: `Failed to find module` ... (a couple others, please let me know in the comments if relevant)
- E: `Failed to mount /boot/efi A start job unit boot-efi.mount has failed` -- I tried examining the logs for this, didn't find much. NOTE: I *do not* see the error telling me it does not know how to mount `vfat`, I think this is a different error.
- W: `Dependency failed for Local File System A start job unit local-fs.target has failed`
- E: `FAT-fs (nvme0n1p4): IO charset iso8859-1 not found`
- N: `systemd-fsckd.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state`

I looked up the ACPI Errors, [there are](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284913/ubuntu-20-04-boot-black-screen-ae-not-found-error-freezing) [a couple](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443398/acpi-bios-error-ae-not-found) [of questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425335/acpi-error-ae-not-found-when-installing-running-any-linux-os) [that have](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272026/acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-sb-pcio-sato-prto-gtf-dssp) similar issues but Im not sure they are relevant too me because one is [unanswered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284913/ubuntu-20-04-boot-black-screen-ae-not-found-error-freezing), [I have an AMD CPU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443398/acpi-bios-error-ae-not-found), [one Im not having the exact same notes, and I dont think Pop!_OS 22.04 is using grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272026/acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-sb-pcio-sato-prto-gtf-dssp) and [I don't have an internet connection in emergency mode (may be driver issues) and I'm not sure its the same error (though I do have an NVIDIA GPU)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425335/acpi-error-ae-not-found-when-installing-running-any-linux-os)

My research on this error shows that sometimes people just have a delay in botting, I left my laptop running overnight and its still hanging. I'm not sure how to turn ACPI off either or if this would help, some people just ignore this error and I'm not sure if its t he root of the problem

As for failing to mount `/boot/efi` I explained some of the steps I already took, and while its obviously a problem, I cant really find what is causing it.

My question is two fold:

1. How do I distinguish the relevant errors/warnings causing this problem
2. What can I do to boot my system properly again?

UPDATE [ 0 ]:

I just tried updating the BIOS and I cant see the Pop!_OS install anymore :(

UPDATE [ 1 ]:
Using the Pop!_OS install live cd, the partition utility is scanning to see if it can recover disks, it says it is going to give my boot partition a new UUID (probably will have to edit `/etc/fdisk`)

Thank you